# How do I properly parse the range information in a unified diff?

Tags: ruby, git, diff

Basically, what I want to do is look at the range information of a unified diff and know exactly which lines of code I should pay attention to.

For instance, this:

```
@@ -1827,7 +1827,7 @@
```

This tells me that in total only 1 line has changed, because the diff shows 3 lines above and below the change (so 7 - 6 = 1), and it also points me to the line 1830 (i.e. 1827 + 3).

To be more pedantic, this particular range information actually tells me that at line 1830, a line was removed (-), and at line 1830 a line was added (+).

Or to make that more obvious consider this range information for another diff:

```
@@ -878,15 +878,13 @@
```

What this is telling me is that at line 881 (878 + 3) 9 lines were deleted (15 - 6), but at line 881 only 7 lines were added (13 - 6).

So the question is, using a regex or some other Ruby string method, how do I pull out the above information easily?

i.e. how do I easily pull out this info:

- <s>Both</s> The line numbers (i.e. just the 1827 or 878), which I can then add + 3 to determine the actual inline number I care about. <s>It has to be both because both lines may not always be identical.</s>
- The number of lines affected (aka the `7`, `15` or `13` right after the `,` in the above examples)
- While I do that, how do I make sure to track the operation (addition or deletion) for each of the operations.

I tried slicing the string and going directly for a character -- e.g. `myString[3]` which gives me `-`, but that's the only character it reliably works for because the line numbers can be 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, etc. So the only way is to just scan the string and then parse it.

**Edit 1**

To add some code to show what I have tried.

Assume I have the contents of a diff in a variable called `@diff_lines`:

```
@diff_lines.each do |diff_line|
  if diff_line.start_with?("@@")
    del_line_num_start = diff_line.split(/@@ /).second.split.first.split(/-/).second.split(/,/).first.to_i + 3
    num_deleted_lines = diff_line.split(/@@ /).second.split.first.split(/-/).second.split(/,/).second.to_i - 6
    add_line_num_start = diff_line.split(/@@ /).second.split.second.split(/\+/).second.split(/,/).first.to_i + 3
    num_added_lines = diff_line.split(/@@ /).second.split.second.split(/\+/).second.split(/,/).second.to_i - 6
```

As you can see, the above works....but it is quite horrendous to look at and is OBVIOUSLY not very DRY.

Ideally I would like to be able to achieve the same thing, but just cleaner.

Comment: The goal of your parsing isn't exactly clear here, it'd be better if you structured things in terms of input and expected output, plus there's no code that demonstrates what you've tried, the most important component of a question here.

Comment: @tadman See updated question with code.

Comment: You'd probably be better off with a regular expression to bust that thing apart into components than repeatedly hitting it with the `split` hammer.

Comment: Yeh....that's exactly what I am looking for. Any thoughts? @tadman

Comment: Is it just me that does not undertand the example? I can't follow your explanation, the diff code examples do not match the lines you are mentioning in the comments... please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general idea is to write a regular expression that has capture groups in it (`(...)`) to pick apart that string into something useful. For example:

```
diff_line.match(/\A@@\s+\-(\d+),(\d+)\s+\+(\d+),(\d+)\s+@@/)
```

This yields a [MatchData](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/MatchData.html) object on a successful match. You can then apply this to some variables like:

```
if (m = diff_line.match(...))
  a_start, a_len, b_start, b_len = m[1..4].map(&:to_i)
end
```

Then you can do whatever computations you need to do with these numbers.

If you're ever having trouble visualizing what a regular expression does, try a tool like [Rubular](http://rubular.com) to better illustrate the internals.